# Optimizing slow join on large-ish tables

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

Any suggestions on how to speed up this join?

```
Activity.joins('JOIN relationships as owner ON owner.person_id = activities.owner_id ')
```

There's an index on both 'person_id' and 'owner_id'

ANALYZE:

```
=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE for: SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" JOIN relationships as owner ON owner.person_id = activities.owner_id
                                                                 QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=45827.59..598928.22 rows=17869287 width=78) (actual time=376.884..4954.592 rows=2963220 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (activities.owner_id = owner.person_id)
   ->  Seq Scan on activities  (cost=0.00..164430.24 rows=6484724 width=78) (actual time=0.036..646.086 rows=6484724 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=25685.15..25685.15 rows=1227715 width=4) (actual time=376.635..376.636 rows=1221946 loops=1)
         Buckets: 131072  Batches: 32  Memory Usage: 2382kB
         ->  Seq Scan on relationships owner  (cost=0.00..25685.15 rows=1227715 width=4) (actual time=106.584..228.241 rows=1221946 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.236 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 10
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 1.108 ms, Inlining 2.677 ms, Optimization 61.629 ms, Emission 42.139 ms, Total 107.552 ms
 Execution Time: 5032.112 ms
(12 rows)
```

Comment: Why do you need all 2963220 rows in your application?

Comment: We store a lot of "activities" -- things like posts, and all the associated comments, and more. We really only care about those with a timestamp within the last 7 days though

Comment: Well then you should limit the query to retrieve only rows from the last 7 days, instead of retrieving all of them.

Comment: Can you please show your table and index definitions? Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning.

Comment: I am doing that, but in investigating why the full query is slow I stripped it down and realized that it's slow even with just the join, but now that you mention it I see why this part is slow. I'll add pieces of the query back bit by bit and see where I end up.

Comment: You get 3 million records in 5 seconds, that's about 600.000 records per second. What are your expectations? How fast should this query be?

Comment: You don't speed up a join. You speed up a query. There could be better executiion paths you are not seeing if you just look at the join.